# в Laravel5 вернуть результат обработки вида в качестве параметра json

Tags: json, laravel, view

Всем привет

Подскажите, в **Laravel 5.4.22** хочу вернуть результат  обработки вида в качестве параметра `json`, вроде:

```
ob_start();
view('.settings.settings_images', $commonVarsArray );
$html= ob_get_contents();
echo '<pre>$html::'.print_r($html,true).'</pre>'; //СТРОКА ПУСТА
ob_end_clean();
return \Response::json(['html'=>$html, 'settings_sliderImagesList'=>$settings_sliderImagesList, 'rows_count'=>count($settings_sliderImagesList)]);
```

Но `$html` пуста... А как правильно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Хелпер view() возвращает объект типа Illuminate\View\View, который содержит метод render(), возвращающий строковое представление обработанной вьюшки:

```
$html = view('.settings.settings_images', $commonVarsArray)->render();
```